# MATLAB: Need to replace all NaN in an array in matlab?

Tags: matlab

How can I replace all `NaN` in an array in matlab?
I want to replace all `NaN` value with some infinite value.
My code is shown below:

```
   Z=
          NaN
           NaN
      23.0490
        2.8444
          -Inf
       NaN
       NaN
       19.0081
        5.1412
       39.4275
    6.3174
      -Inf
       NaN
       NaN
   19.0081
    5.1412
   28.2539
    9.3265
   37.7239
   11.9736
  -16.4239
    9.3265
   -8.2900
  -25.6488
       NaN
       NaN
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Have you tried:

```
Z(isnan(Z)) = inf
```